# Android app crashes on upgrade SDK 24 to 26

Tags: android, react-native

My React Native 0.42 app with `targetSdk=24` works 100% but PlayStore now requires `targetSdk=26` minimum, if I switch the version, app crashes in some devices, but don't in all devices (without standards or specific versions).

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@a57d7dc -- permission denied for window type 2003`

**build.grandle on APP:**

```java
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.guidoo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 136
        versionName "1.9.4"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
            pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "80bf364c-1450-4ced-a491-166b0643e550",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
          if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
              storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
              storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
              keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
              keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
          }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2 ]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Some part of AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
            android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

**The Error on logcat:**

````
    Process: com.guidoo, PID: 7513
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@a57d7dc -- permission denied for window type 2003
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:789)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:92)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:330)
        at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSupportManagerImpl$4.run(DevSupportManagerImpl.java:336)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)```
````

Comment: You can have a quick search on Google about the error you are getting, i.e., permission denied for window type 2003

Comment: @Kartik I found some solutions in Google but nothing help me ;/

Comment: Someone said this on GitHub issues page for react-native. Upgrading to 0.52.0 react native fixed it for me.

Comment: You can also check this link https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4043

Comment: @Kartik did not work, same problem